# Limit data points with chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, points

I've setup a line chart with [chart js](https://www.chartjs.org/). In this picture my dots are too big but that is not my problem. There are too many points.

**Is there a way to limit the number of points?**

One point every 5 points would be a good solution.

[image]

Comment: Related Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354304/chartjs-2-scaling-lots-of-data-points. Please +1 for this GitHub feature req (Related): https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you will need to select data points with 4 points skipped manually.
Here is the code example to have you get the idea.

```
var reducedDataPoints = []
for(let [item, index] of xAxisDataPoints.entries()) {
  if(index % 5 === 0) {
    reducedDataPoints.push(item)
  }
}
```

You also need to do the same on the `y` axis to get it to work. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Pakpoom, may you kindly provide a full example to how use your cose inside the chart's options?

Comment: This solution works fine in terms of displaying less points, but there is a big problem. It misses highs and lows of the chart and it can thus plot the wrong chart.