# Implementing Data Decimation in vue chartjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I've been trying and failing to implement data decimation in vue chartJS, I'm assuming parsing is the hurdle stopping me as it is the one requirement I cant seem to fulfil.

1. The dataset must have an indexAxis of 'x'
2. The dataset must be a line
3. The X axis for the dataset must be either a 'linear' or 'time' type axis
4. Data must not need parsing, i.e. parsing must be false
5. The dataset object must be mutable. The plugin stores the original data as dataset._data and then defines a new data property on the dataset.

My current chart options are:

```
oilOptions: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        y: {
            ... // Formatting and title
        },
        x: {
            type: 'time'
            ... // Formatting and title
        }
    },
    plugins: {
        title: {
            ...
        },
        zoom: {
            ...
        },
        decimation: {
            enabled: true,
            algorithm: 'lttb',
            samples: 500
        }
```

The dataset is historical Brent oil price data structured like:

```
{
    labels: [
        "1987-05-20",
        "1987-05-21",
        ...
     ],
     datasets: [
        label: "Brent Oil Price",
        fill: false,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
        tension: 0.5,
        pointRadius: 0,
        // parsing: false (This stops data from rendering anyway)
        data: [
                18,
                18,
                ...
        ]
     ]
```

I'm using vue-chartjs but that shouldn't be an issue.

Any help would be appreciated, my other option would be to reduce the data on the backend before passing it to the client, or have a separately saved reduced data set on my DB.

Comment: You may also have to explicitly define `options.parsing: false` as stated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71987156/2358409

Comment: I already am, but I think my issue comes from somewhere else. I changed my data format to the `{x,y}` format but am now getting an issue where [only my first two data points are being displayed](https://gyazo.com/af0638ce57fcadcd9f1ff519c8743c60), anyways I will push this aside for now and just save a reduced data set to my DB and load it alongside the full one.

Comment: When using point data format (`{x, y}`), make sure to not define `data.labels` the same time.

Answer (score 1):

No parsing means that you need to provide the data like the internal format so no labels array and objects in your data array like so:

```
{
  datasets: [{
    label: "Brent Oil Price",
    fill: false,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
    tension: 0.5,
    pointRadius: 0,
    parsing: false
    data: [{
        x: '1987-05-20',
        y: 5
      },
      {
        x: '1987-05-21',
        y: 6
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

The internal data format can be found in the docs [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/charts/line.html#internal-data-format)

Comment: Thanks. didn't know I had to use that data format. Having another issue now though, with parsing set to false only my first two data points (1987-05-20 and 05-21) are being displayed (even with the decimation plugin off), with parsing set to true everything gets rendered again until I interact with the graph and zoom. I've already checked that all of the data is being loaded. [graph](https://gyazo.com/af0638ce57fcadcd9f1ff519c8743c60) and [data](https://gyazo.com/cf32163eb16b07a025c2fef28d686e12), any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a reproducable sample, makes it a lot easyer to work with?

Comment: Quickly made a vue with local data: [vue/code](https://pastebin.com/5EwHNhUV) and [data/json](https://pastebin.com/raw/redEapyn) and it still happens, I think I might put this to the side for now and make a reduced data set separately and just load it alongside the full dataset. Thanks for the info about the data format tho!